# Best practice to save private images on a webserver ASP Net Core/Angular

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In my Angular app users can register/logged in and upload private images. This images are shown immediately in the formular after the upload.
At the moment the images a stored in folder

`string imageDictionary = $"{_HostingEnvironment.WebRootPath}\\{User.Identity.Name}\\UploadFiles\\";`

The folder and image name is stored in the database.

What is the best way to make sure that the images can only be access by the user how are logged in?
At the moment is it possible to call the image if the link are known.

Is it enough if I disable directory browsing and give the image a random created name?

I use for backend ASP Net Core and for frontend Angular version 7.

Comment: You could create a folder with the id of the user, and save it in there. But you'd still need to check if the id requested, matches the id of the logged in user.

Comment: My goal is, how can I achieve that the images can't be access by another user. Will it be save enough when I create a random folder name and a random file-name? Theoretically when a user guess the link to the folder and image he can open the image in browser.

Comment: Either you make random enough to make it secure against guessing (although a known link can then still be shared), or you serve the files dynamically (through a controller action) which would allow you to use the full authorization capabilities to protect the resource. You could then also store those files in a database instead of writing them to disk.

Comment: if you don't want to store the files in database the only way will be hide the image behind a random created folder name? What if you store the image outside the webroot and copy the file into the webroot when the user logged in. When the user logged out or after token is expired the images in the folder and file will be deleted.

Comment: No, you don’t _have_ to store them in the database (I was just suggesting that this would now be possible). You can also store them outside of ther web root and have a dynamic file handler access the file from outside. You should’t copy or move files around though.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use Azure Blob storage since already have security protection

If you want to store your file in wwwroot folder you need to add middleware to check for user permission before you let them see the file because wwwroot folder is a public folder which everyone can access